# How do I transfer email address from old Stack Exchange account to new account?

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, email

I have an old Stack Overflow account with a registered email address. However, this account is old and I don't want to use it anymore. I want to create a brand new account. BUT, I registered my big important email address with the old account and want to use this address for the new one!! But I receive the error, "this email address is already registered with an account".

Is it possible for me to unregister my email address from the old account and re-register with the new one. Preferably, not deleting the old account. As I will still be referring to it on occasion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to https://stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/current and remove the Stack Exchange login (make sure you have another login method that is still valid). You can then add a Stack Exchange login to another new account.

Comment: Great! If I decided to keep the old Login, would the public know I have 2 logins? Also, is the OpenID just my name?

Comment: @Gregory The public can't see your logins. I'm not sure I understand your second question.

Comment: Well I have the option of adding a LogIn using Facebook/yahoo etc. Then there is an option for using an OpenID. My first login uses Facebook. I want my second one to use my email address and name. How is this achieved? What do I input for the OpenID. Sorry if I seem a bit ignorant, I'm very new to all this

Comment: @Gregory [The duplicate linked to by rene has a great step-by-step tutorial.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114704)

Comment: I only have one login to choose from and that is with my Facebook email. Yet when I try to register with my google email it logs me into my Facebook account. As if both are connected. Hence, I have no option of removing my Google email from my account because under my logins all that is available is my Facebook email

Comment: Nevermind, I had to change my email address in profile info, this surprisingly fixed the issue. Thanks for the help